# NEST compound queries which must all be satisfied

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

```
var availableToField = Infer.Field<Project>(f => f.Availablity.AvailableTo);
var availableFromField = Infer.Field<Project>(f => f.Availablity.AvailableFrom);
var nameField = Infer.Field<Project>(f => f.Contact.Name);

var active_date_to = new DateRangeQuery(){
            Name = "toDate",
            Boost = 1.1,
            Field = "availablity.availableTo",
            GreaterThan = DateTime.Now,
            TimeZone = "+01:00",
            Format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:SS||dd.MM.yyyy"
        };
var active_date_from = new DateRangeQuery(){
            Name = "from",
            Boost = 1.1,
            Field = "availablity.availableFrom",
            LessThanOrEqualTo = DateTime.Now,
            TimeZone = "+01:00",
            Format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:SS||dd.MM.yyyy"
        };

public ISearchResult<Project> Search(SearchCriteria criteria)
        {var ret = _client.Search<Project>(s =>
                s.Query(q =>


                        active_date_from &&
                        active_date_to &&
                        q.Match(d => d.Query(criteria.FreeText))
                        ).From(criteria.CurrentPage).Size(criteria.Take)
                        .From(criteria.CurrentPage)
                        .Take(criteria.Take)

            );
result.Total = ret.Total;
            result.Page = criteria.CurrentPage;
            result.PerPage = criteria.Take;
            result.Results = ret.Documents;
            return result;
}
```

what im trying to do is get the results matching the freetext but are also withing the pricerange..
somehow though what i get is an invalid NEST response build from a unsuccessful low level call on POST... and in consequence an empty query.
there are no compiling errors.

does anyone have an idea where i could have gone wrong or what im missing?

the other thing i tried was

```
var mustClauses = new List<QueryContainer>();
            mustClauses.Add(active_date_from);
            mustClauses.Add(active_date_to);            
            mustClauses.Add(new TermQuery
            {
                Field = "contact.name",
                Value = criteria.FreeText
            });

            var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<Project>()
            {
                Size = 10,
                From = 0,
                Query = new BoolQuery
                {
                    Must = mustClauses

                }

            };

            var ret = _client.Search<Project>(searchRequest);

            result.Total = ret.Total;
            result.Page = criteria.CurrentPage;
            result.PerPage = criteria.Take;
            result.Results = ret.Documents;
```

which got me pretty much the same results.. (read: none)

is there something im missing?

edit:
however.. this:

```
var ret = _client.Search<Project>(s => s.Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.DisplayName).Query(criteria.FreeText))));
```

gives me exactly what i want (without the validation of the dates of course and only looking at one field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, the `match` query is missing a `field` property which is needed for the query. Because of NEST's [conditionless query behaviour](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/verbatim-and-strict-query-usage.html), the query is not serialized as part of the request.  The two date range queries are serialized however.

Here's a simple example that you may find useful to get the correct query you're looking for

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "projects";
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, new InMemoryConnection())
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex )
        .PrettyJson()
        .DisableDirectStreaming()
        .OnRequestCompleted(response =>
            {
                if (response.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        $"{response.HttpMethod} {response.Uri} \n" +
                        $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.RequestBodyInBytes)}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{response.HttpMethod} {response.Uri}");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();

                if (response.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Status: {response.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                             $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ResponseBodyInBytes)}\n" +
                             $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Status: {response.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                             $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
                }
            });

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    var availableToField = Infer.Field<Project>(f => f.Availablity.AvailableTo);
    var availableFromField = Infer.Field<Project>(f => f.Availablity.AvailableFrom);
    var nameField = Infer.Field<Project>(f => f.Contact.Name);

    var active_date_to = new DateRangeQuery
    {
        Name = "toDate",
        Boost = 1.1,
        Field = availableToField,
        GreaterThan = DateTime.Now,
        TimeZone = "+01:00",
        Format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:SS||dd.MM.yyyy"
    };
    var active_date_from = new DateRangeQuery
    {
        Name = "from",
        Boost = 1.1,
        Field = availableFromField,
        LessThanOrEqualTo = DateTime.Now,
        TimeZone = "+01:00",
        Format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:SS||dd.MM.yyyy"
    };

    var ret = client.Search<Project>(s => s
        .Query(q =>
            active_date_from &&
            active_date_to && q
            .Match(d => d
                .Query("free text")
            )
        )
        .From(0)
        .Size(10)
    );
}

public class Project
{
    public Availibility Availablity { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Availibility
{
    public DateTime AvailableFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime AvailableTo { get; set; }
}
```

Your current query generates

```
POST http://localhost:9200/projects/project/_search?pretty=true 
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "availablity.availableFrom": {
              "lte": "2017-07-21T10:01:01.456794+10:00",
              "time_zone": "+01:00",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:SS||dd.MM.yyyy",
              "_name": "from",
              "boost": 1.1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "availablity.availableTo": {
              "gt": "2017-07-21T10:01:01.456794+10:00",
              "time_zone": "+01:00",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:SS||dd.MM.yyyy",
              "_name": "toDate",
              "boost": 1.1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If a `nameField` is added as the field for the match query you get

```
POST http://localhost:9200/projects/project/_search?pretty=true 
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "availablity.availableFrom": {
              "lte": "2017-07-21T10:02:23.896385+10:00",
              "time_zone": "+01:00",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:SS||dd.MM.yyyy",
              "_name": "from",
              "boost": 1.1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "availablity.availableTo": {
              "gt": "2017-07-21T10:02:23.896385+10:00",
              "time_zone": "+01:00",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:SS||dd.MM.yyyy",
              "_name": "toDate",
              "boost": 1.1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "contact.name": {
              "query": "free text"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Remove `InMemoryConnection` from `ConnectionSettings` if you actually want to execute the query against Elasticsearch and see the results.

The `range` query is a structured query where a document either matches or doesn't match the predicate. Because of this, it can be wrapped in a `bool` query `filter` clause which will forgo calculating a score for it and perform better. Because no scoring occurs, boost is not needed.

Putting this together

```
var availableToField = Infer.Field<Project>(f => f.Availablity.AvailableTo);
var availableFromField = Infer.Field<Project>(f => f.Availablity.AvailableFrom);
var nameField = Infer.Field<Project>(f => f.Contact.Name);

var active_date_to = new DateRangeQuery
{
    Name = "toDate",
    Field = availableToField,
    GreaterThan = DateTime.Now,
    TimeZone = "+01:00",
    Format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:SS||dd.MM.yyyy"
};
var active_date_from = new DateRangeQuery
{
    Name = "from",
    Field = availableFromField,
    LessThanOrEqualTo = DateTime.Now,
    TimeZone = "+01:00",
    Format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:SS||dd.MM.yyyy"
};

var ret = client.Search<Project>(s => s
    .Query(q =>
        +active_date_from &&
        +active_date_to && q
        .Match(d => d
            .Field(nameField)
            .Query("free text")
        )
    )
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
);
```

You may also want to explore modelling available from and to as a [`date_range` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html)

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot. the time format was also something it didnt like and gave me an "invalid" response. but thanks to you it workes now

Comment: the format is only needed if the date that you're sending in is different from the format on the date field mapping. It's used to parse the incoming date